# Enterprise Library Strong Naming Guidance Package

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, enterprise-library

For the life of me I can not find the Enterprise Library Strong Naming Guidance Package download for Enterprise Library 4.1

I need this to sign the assemblies to add them to the GAC.

Does anybody know where I can find it?  I can't find it anywhere on the www.codeplex.com/entlib or www.codeplex.com/entlibcontrib websites.

HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx), the shipped binaries are already strong named, so you should be [good to go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203283.aspx).

EDIT: If you modified the source, use [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140121.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The guidance package was checked in to EntLibContrib: 
http://entlibcontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx

See changeset 18160