# How to add C# dll in Visual C++ console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll, dllimport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use c# Dll in vc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980808/how-to-use-c-sharp-dll-in-vc)

I have created a class in the c sharp and made the DLL of the class now i want to use the methods in the DLL file in my VC++ project.

I know how to add the .lib file in VC++ project but how to add a DLL file in VC++ project I don't know.

I want to create the object of the class that i defined in the DLL in my VC++ project and through the object i want to access its methods.

When I tried this and I got following error:

```
support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 error "referenced assembly entlibcontrib.data.mysql does not have strong name"
```

Please guide me through this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/980808/796036

Comment: _"Please guide me through this."_ - done any research? What have you found?

Comment: @CodeCaster i tryed this  and i got this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 error "referenced assembly entlibcontrib.data.mysql does not have strong name"

Comment: @Ajinkya then mention that in your question. Or even better, download the enterprise library that has strong-named assemblies or [do so yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659408/enterprise-library-strong-naming-guidance-package).

Comment: @CodeCaster i went to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736 i did this C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\NiproDAAB\IISWebFrameworkDAAB\bi n\Release>RegAsm.exe IISWebFrameworkDAAB.dll Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004. All rights reserved. Types registered successfully  but there is no .tlb file as said under the heading "Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code" under "7"point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind to make the DLL visible to COM and follow [this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736). For the visibility you can either change the `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]` or via the integrated property editor of Visual Studio.

Comment: @Christianlvicevic Sir i did what is given in above link but when i did RegAsm.exe My.dll under the heading "Register the Managed DLL for Use with COM or with Native C++" i get "RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered"

Comment: Sir i got the "Types registered successfully" but there is no .tlb file as said under the heading "Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code" under "7"point

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\NiproDAAB\IISWebFrameworkDAAB\bi
n\Release>RegAsm.exe IISWebFrameworkDAAB.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004. All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully

Answer (score 0):

your c# dll need to be ComVisible attribute

```
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
```

For more info see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

If you are non-managed, C++ project then you must use COM interop to access the assembly. After which you can access it like any other COM component

Comment: Sir i did what is given in above link but when i did RegAsm.exe My.dll under the heading "Register the Managed DLL for Use with COM or with Native C++" i get "RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered"

Comment: Sir i got the "Types registered successfully" but there is no .tlb file as said under the heading "Call the Managed DLL from Native C++ Code" under "7"point

Comment: i did this C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\NiproDAAB\IISWebFrameworkDAAB\bi
n\Release>RegAsm.exe IISWebFrameworkDAAB.dll
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1998-2004. All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully